# Google sheets query pulling data that makes no sense

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

All of a sudden when a new order was added to my sheet with all orders my query function started acting up and i dont understand why it is doing this. My original query line is as follows: =transpose(query({'Beställningar'!$A$4:$RR};"SELECT "&JOIN(", ";ArrayFormula("Col"&SEQUENCE(KOLUMNER('Beställningar'!$A$4:$RR)/3;1;KOLUMN(A1)+5-1;2)))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&$L$4&"'")) and worked perfectly fine before. Now it returns the correct values, in this case every 2nd column starting with column 5 but it for some reason also includes the top row of the orders sheet ("beställningar") where Col 1 isn't equal to L4.

I even tried a simple one: =QUERY('Beställningar'!A4:RR;"Select A where A = '"&K4&"'") and the result i get is: 162006092023115622
undefined05092023120605. How is this possible? How can the query function return two different values when i ask it to return the value that matches the cell? The correct value in this case is "undefined05092023120605" and 162006092023115622 is also returned for some reason. I know the undefined part looks weird but thats just an issue with the website currently and it worked fine with the same issue before.

Would love to get a solution to this.

Comment: Also the result: 162006092023115622 is always returned no matter what i change K4 to. Seems like a bug to me but i dont know what to do...

Comment: Could be a possible case of [mixed data type](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mixed-data-type-issue-in-query/) thing that query behaves abnormal!

Comment: Well, i thought so to but all data is regular text and it still gives me the same result

Comment: Share a sample sheet by recreating this issue so that we can test it out directly

Comment: When i copy the values and test it in a new sheet it works as intended so

Answer (score 0):

QUERY has a third argument that defines if the data that are you grabbing has headers or not. If you leave it by default, it will consider the first row as headers (hence, not filtering it). Add ";" and a "0" or "False" at the end of the QUERY:

```
=transpose(query({'Beställningar'!$A$4:$RR};"SELECT "&JOIN(", ";ArrayFormula("Col"&SEQUENCE(KOLUMNER('Beställningar'!$A$4:$RR)/3;1;KOLUMN(A1)+5-1;2)))&" WHERE Col1 = '"&$L$4&"'";0))
```